# RequireJS loads scripts before the view is initialized

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs

I have a Backbone view as a requirejs module. The problem is that requirejs load the http://localhost/remote/script/here.js before the view is even initialized. Is it because the script isn't inside a requirejs module?

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'undescore',
    'backbone',
    'http://localhost/remote/script/here'   
], function($, _, Backbone, Luajs){
    var View = Backbone.View.extend({
        initialize : function(options) {
        },
        render : function() {
            this.$el.html('<p>my view</p>')
            return this;
        }
    });

    return View;
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The array you have as the first argument to `define` *is* the depedencies of your view. So yes it is loaded and parsed before the `View`.
Also note that unless you use modified versions of backbone and underscore, they ar not AMD compliant. You will need to wrap them with a plugin to load them properly.

Comment: i use the modified version of backbone and underscore. In order to load asynchronous my scripts I have to wrap them in a define() ?

Comment: Modules in the requirements argument of define are loaded asyncronously. When they are loaded the function in the define is called.

Comment: Hmm so i have no control on when to load them?

Comment: Well normally not. As I say, dependencies are loaded before your module is initialized. If you want to load "inside" the module, use `mydep = require('mydep');`.

Answer (score 0):

you try to define the view Backbone after the load the module.
You can do this, in the define () method of RequireJS. The array of this function contains parameters  that defines module dependencies.